# What performance requirements are implied by the term "telecom applications"?

Tags: datasheet, terminology, telecommunications

I've noticed the term *telecom applications* or just *telecom* in a few datasheets I've come across, and in the book I'm working through, the phrase *"In high-speed dc-dc switchers for the telecom market ..."* appears.

What kind of requirements does that term imply? Does that mean a device that appears in my mobile phone or perhaps a gigabit router? What's special about those applications in general that one might characterize a particular device or circuit as suitable for it?

Comment: It probably just means the sales team has at least one customer in the the telecom industry that they think they can sell that part to. It might also mean they've passed some industry-specific qualification test, such as Telcordia GR-468.

Comment: As a quick answer: no it doesn't normally refer to mobile phones or home routers, but most likely to something like a rack-mounted (kW power) SMPS. Or possibly to the board-level converters used in used in the (rack-mounted) routing equipment. Without more specifics as to which datasheets you're talking about, we can't really say.

Comment: Good point @RespawnedFluff, I should have thought to provide links. Here's one: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MMBTA92.pdf for  a so-called "high-voltage" PNP in an SOT23 package, which now that I think about it, I came across in the course of salvaging discretes from an old 2Wire DSL modem. So now KyranF's answer is making more sense to me :)

Comment: Eh, that's just a lowly transistor (albeit a fairly high-voltage one, 300V) rather than the DC/DC converters you were talking about initially. They suggest telepho**ny** not telecom applications, which is a bit different. I'm not sure exactly what telephony apps they have in mind. I've opened a bunch of phones and even DSL concetrators, and I don't remember seeing that kind of HV parts. You might want to ask about this transistor as a separate question.

Comment: That transistor is a common HV model, made by several manufacturers. I've checked [ON's datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MMBTA92LT1-D.PDF) and it says nothing about telephony and neither does the datasheet from [Diodes Inc.](http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/ds30060.pdf). But ST's datasheet proved the most explicit suggesting "Video amplifier circuits (rgb cathode current control)" and "Telephone wireline interface (hook switches, dialer circuits)". The first application is obvoius... the 2nd not so much to me. I've not seen HV transistors like that used in phones.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks again @RespawnedFluff :)  I think my key takeaway is when seeing the application domain "telecom" to first think of circuit voltages above the normal-ish (for ICs anyway) 36V \$V_\text{CC}\$range, possibly 60V as a worst case given the range up to 57V mentioned in the resource you linked below that still counts as nominally "48V" :)  I'm still not clear on why fast transient response is required, that might be worth an additional answer. I'm assuming it's because there are fast current transients due to high digital transmission (and therefore switching) speeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of at least one requirement for the telecom market and the DC-DC switching (or even linear) voltage regulators involved -  they need to handle +-48V on the input. This is quite high for modern voltage regulators in most of the industries/fields I've dealt with, and this high voltage is a remnant of the old days of telephone lines having to transmit signals over long distances, 48V was found to be useful for long range transmission and still relatively safe for humans in case someone touched it.

At my university, 50VDC was the limit before it become illegal/very high risk/must be enclosed and never touched while live.

This is only a guess, but another "requirement" for telecoms grade regulators I could see as being important is high power supply rejection ratio (PSRR) on the regulators, low EMI (for modern EMI standards), and good line/load regulation (related in part to the PSRR).

The "high speed" implies that a requirement for telecoms power regulation is that the regulator topology has fast transient response, meaning multi-phase DC-DC converters (synchronous buck converters, for example) or high frequency converters for faster and tighter control over the load.

Comment: 48V is nominal; just like mains power, it can have fairly large variations, up to 60V DC. See Ericsson's [technical paper 018](http://archive.ericsson.net/service/internet/picov/get?DocNo=31/28701-FGB101378) for a discussion of just the safety requirements.

Comment: For an idea what a typical rack-mounted telco 48V psu has inside (and some perf specs) see [this Infineon presentation](http://www.tecnoimprese.it/user/0900_Doc/201210191643362kW%20Telecom%20SMPS%20Design%20Guidelines.pdf).

Comment: Very helpful links @RespawnedFluff, thanks for these; exactly the kind of real-life "what's the job to get done" type of insight I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

"Telecom" power supplies tend to have the following requirements or side-effects:

- **Robustness**, because you don't want to see your internet connection
  fail, and because they are sometimes installed in remote locations,
  making service very expensive.
- **Hot-Swap** is OK, because they are often installed in racks, in
  parallel for redundancy, and you don't want to shut down the whole
  rack when you pull or push one supply.
- **Good efficiency / low loss**, because racks contain many devices and supplies, and
  for a whole floor of racks, cooling becomes very expensive.
- **An economic threat** to any power supply manufacturer relying mostly on that one market, because one
  year, so many are required that they become the main focus of the
  company, and the next year, the dotcom marked goes all bust, and
  takes the power supply manufacturer with it. Has happened multiple times (dotcom bubble, cell phone/mobile internet ups and downs, "fast" internet infrastructure boom, ...)

For the technical properties, power supplies tend to be labeled "telecom" for many of the same reasons IT stuff tends to be labeled "server".

Comment: This really helps add color to my understanding, thanks zebonaut :) I suppose somehow I'd thought of telecom still meaning phones, but I'm starting to get the idea that it's really all about data (digital) telecommunications these days (even if that data carries voice).